# Discord.py bot to move users to a different voice channel

Tags: python

I am currently writing a bot using the discord.py module (reference can be found here: http://rapptz.github.io/discord.py/api.html).

Is there any way for the bot (script) to move users to a different voice channel?

For example, user X is playing 'Star Citizen' but is in the 'BF4' channel. The bot will move the user to the correct 'Star Citizen' voice channel.

Any help would be appreciated (I am new to python and SO).

Answer (score 3):

There is a function to move a member:
http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.move_member

And function to get the new game playing:
http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update

Other than that, on stackoverflow you should come with something nyou have already tried, instead of coming in and saying "hey how do I do x"