# Getting a discord voice channel ID by name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a voice channel and then moving all members to it. The problem is: i couldn't figure out how to get the channel's id correctly for the move_to function. Here is the code:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx): 
    await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel("TEST")
    test_get = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.channels, name="TEST", type="ChannelType.voice")
    await asyncio.sleep(2.0)
    for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.move_to(channel=test_get)
        except:
            pass
```

Using this, the bot just remove all the members from the voice channels, instead of moving them to **TEST**.

Comment: Did u check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548286/discord-py-bot-to-move-users-to-a-different-voice-channel

Comment: Yea, i did this

Answer (score 2):

To get the Channel ID, you should [read this guide](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-), also getting the ID every time is very inefficient, you can store the channel in a variable and delete it after:

```
channel = await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel("TEST") # Creates the channel
await channel.delete() # Deletes the channel
```